# Elasticsearch POD in kubernetes randomly fails with error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I deployed Elasticsearch 7.17.9 using a helm chart in the AWS EKS cluster. While installing/upgrading the deployment randomly one POD goes to an ERROR state. Below is the exception found in the POD logs. Why this is happening even though all three replicas use the same image? This occurs even though X-PACK security is disabled.

```
ElasticsearchException[Could not find plugin class [org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security]]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security];
Likely root cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:872)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPluginClass(PluginsService.java:777)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:738)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:533)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:411)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:169)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:160)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:125)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log
2023-05-23 19:03:59,695328 UTC [432] INFO  Main.cc@111 Parent process died - ML controller exiting
```

Comment: Check if you have enough node memory

Comment: If there is no enough memory then k8s will not schedule the POD in that node right?

Comment: I have few issues these days all kind of random errors come class loading was once of them. This try `kubectl get events`

Comment: Its not giving any usefull information. I tried to use elasticsearch docker version 8.5.1 and whenever the third replica comes up it started to throw class not found exception for some of the Azure relevant plugins. Bit strange. Whatever the version use the third pod initialization always fails with some class not found error